# Plot a function vertically in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**Question:**
How do I to plot a function "in a vertical way" in Python.

**Explanation/Clarification:**
Plotted already is function 1 (red in the figure below). This is a normal "horizontal plot". I need to insert a function plotted vertically as is shown as the blue line in the figure below.

So, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, 
                   bins=10, 
                   range=None, 
                   normed=False, 
                   weights=None, 
                   cumulative=False, 
                   bottom=None, 
                   histtype=u'bar', 
                   align=u'mid', 
                   orientation=u'vertical', 
                   rwidth=None, 
                   log=False, 
                   color=None, 
                   label=None, 
                   stacked=False, 
                   hold=None, 
                   **kwargs)
```

Most matplotlib functions have orientation, change that to vertical. Otherwise please give more details so we can help.

Comment: I am literally drawing my question, so what is unclear ("give more details")?
I guess I will look into whether "plt.plot(...)" has an "orientiation" option is what I am gathering from your comment.

Comment: In the "hist" case, how is this function aligned along the x-axis? Say I want it plotted vertically at position x=4?

Comment: You could be plotting with bokeh or any other library. Or even rolling your own, hence I asked for more details in case this was not relevant to your question.

Comment: Of course being directed to a library that solves my question is relevant?